# Check if AWS Lambda function completed the job

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am currently sending a file to be transcoded to my AWS lambda function.  After I send the file, I send a notification to the `SQS` for some external aplication to start downloading the transcoded files.

The problem is, sometimes, the download of the files happen before the Lambda function completed.

How can I only send the notification to `SQS` after the Lambda completed.

I tried getting the `Job.Status` as follow, but not sure how to query it again if `Status` is not `Complete`.

Here is my code:

```
using (var eClient = new AmazonElasticTranscoderClient())
                    {

                        var response = await this.S3Client.GetObjectMetadataAsync(s3Event.Bucket.Name, s3Event.Object.Key);

                        var videoPresets = new List<Preset>();
                        var presetRequest = new ListPresetsRequest();
                        ListPresetsResponse presetResponse;
                        do
                        {
                            presetResponse = await eClient.ListPresetsAsync(presetRequest);
                            videoPresets.AddRange(presetResponse.Presets);
                            presetRequest.PageToken = presetResponse.NextPageToken;
                        } while (presetResponse.NextPageToken != null);

                        var pipelines = new List<Pipeline>();
                        var pipelineRequest = new ListPipelinesRequest();
                        ListPipelinesResponse pipelineResponse;
                        do
                        {
                            pipelineResponse = await eClient.ListPipelinesAsync(pipelineRequest);
                            pipelines.AddRange(pipelineResponse.Pipelines);
                            pipelineRequest.PageToken = pipelineResponse.NextPageToken;
                        } while (pipelineResponse.NextPageToken != null);

                        var pipeLine = s3Event.Bucket.Name.ToLower().Contains("test") ? pipelines.First(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains("test")) : pipelines.First(p => !p.Name.ToLower().Contains("test"));

                        //HLS Stuff for Apple
                        var usablePreset = videoPresets.Where(p => p.Name.Contains("HLS") && !p.Name.Contains("HLS Video")).ToList();
                        var hlsPresets = new List<Preset>();
                        foreach (var preset in usablePreset)
                        {
                            var resolution = preset.Name.Replace("System preset: HLS ", "");
                            switch (resolution)
                            {
                                case "2M":
                                case "1M":
                                case "400k":
                                    hlsPresets.Add(preset);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                        var jobReq = new CreateJobRequest
                        {
                            PipelineId = pipeLine.Id,
                            Input = new JobInput() { Key = fileName, },
                            OutputKeyPrefix = outPutPrefix
                            //OutputKeyPrefix = "LambdaTest/" + playlistName + "/"
                        };
                        var outputs = new List<CreateJobOutput>();

                        var playlistHLS = new CreateJobPlaylist() { Name = "HLS_" + playlistName, Format = "HLSv3" };
                        foreach (var preset in hlsPresets)
                        {
                            var resolution = preset.Name.Replace("System preset: HLS ", "").Replace(".", "");
                            var newName = resolution + "_" + playlistName;
                            var output = new CreateJobOutput() { Key = newName, PresetId = preset.Id, SegmentDuration = "10" };
                            outputs.Add(output);
                            playlistHLS.OutputKeys.Add(newName);
                        }
                        jobReq.Playlists.Add(playlistHLS);
                        jobReq.Outputs = outputs;
                        //var temp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jobReq);

                        var reply = eClient.CreateJobAsync(jobReq);

                        var transcodingCompleted = reply.Result.Job.Status == "Complete" ? true : false;
                        do {
                            //somehow need to query status again
                        } while (!transcodingCompleted);

                        if (transcodingCompleted)
                            await SendAsync(jobReq.OutputKeyPrefix, pipeLine.OutputBucket);
                    }
```

The part I am interested in:

```
var reply = eClient.CreateJobAsync(jobReq);

                        var transcodingCompleted = reply.Result.Job.Status == "Complete" ? true : false;
                        do {
                            //somehow need to query status again
                        } while (!transcodingCompleted);

                        if (transcodingCompleted)
                            await SendAsync(jobReq.OutputKeyPrefix, pipeLine.OutputBucket);
```

Comment: If you want to catch some job completing, wrap that part of code in class or just in current class create an "JobCompleted" event, which will raise when job done.

Comment: Is it possible for you to give an example of the event thrown by AWS once the job completed?

Comment: Have you considered having your lambda send the message to SQS once it is complete instead?

Comment: This is what the Lambda does.  The problem is, is creates the transcoding pipeline, and this is where all the magic happens, and this is the where I struggle to get the events from. My Lambda completed loading into the pipeline, but that does not mean the pipeline completed it's job.  Anyway, I found a solution, will post an aswer soon